# Problems while trying to understand matrix shapes in Keras?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am learning keras and this is the first time I am using it in a toy example, so I tried the following linear regression, however I got a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`:

In:

```
import pandas as pd
import keras 
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

dims = X.shape[1]
print(dims, 'dims')
print("Building model...")
nb_classes = y.shape[0]
print(nb_classes, 'classes')


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=dims))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
model.fit(X, y)
```

Out:

```
68 dims
Building model...
1000 classes
(1000, 68)
(1000,)
Epoch 1/10

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-7a58187d7756> in <module>()
     19 print(X.shape)
     20 print(y.shape)
---> 21 model.fit(X, y)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, **kwargs)
    662                               shuffle=shuffle,
    663                               class_weight=class_weight,
--> 664                               sample_weight=sample_weight)
    665 
    666     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch)
   1141                               val_f=val_f, val_ins=val_ins, shuffle=shuffle,
   1142                               callback_metrics=callback_metrics,
-> 1143                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1144 
   1145     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1, sample_weight=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch)
    841                 batch_logs['size'] = len(batch_ids)
    842                 callbacks.on_batch_begin(batch_index, batch_logs)
--> 843                 outs = f(ins_batch)
    844                 if not isinstance(outs, list):
    845                     outs = [outs]

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   1601         session = get_session()
   1602         updated = session.run(self.outputs + [self.updates_op],
-> 1603                               feed_dict=feed_dict)
   1604         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   1605 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    764     try:
    765       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 766                          run_metadata_ptr)
    767       if run_metadata:
    768         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    935                 ' to a larger type (e.g. int64).')
    936 
--> 937           np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
    938 
    939           if not subfeed_t.get_shape().is_compatible_with(np_val.shape):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    529 
    530     """
--> 531     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    532 
    533 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Data:

```
X.shape
(1000, 20)
```

labels:

```
y.shape
(1000,)
```

Comment: try `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and reshaping `y = y.reshape((-1, 1))`.

Comment: Thanks, for the help!... I modified and got: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'` @WasiAhmad

Comment: in which line you are getting this error? it seems like you are directly using a tuple where you need only one value of type string, bytes or number. please check the statement where you are getting this error.

Comment: I updated the question with more details @WasiAhmad !

Comment: @tumbleweed What are the types of X and y?

Comment: The types are: `type(X)`
`scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`



`type(y)`
`numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @tumbleweed Both should be numpy arrays or plain lists. That is the problem.

Comment: I did `X = X.A` and it turned into a numpy array, then I got: `TypeError: Error when checking model target: data should be a Numpy array, or list/dict of Numpy arrays. Found: <built-in method tolist of numpy.ndarray object at 0x1071a6e40>...`

Comment: Try X = X.A() - this might help.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinMożejko, I tried it and I got : `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Answer (score 2):

`input_shape` parameter of `Dense()` should be an integer. So, try the following:

```
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, input_dim=dims))
```

From [official documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense):

> **keras.layers.core.Dense**(output_dim, init='glorot_uniform', activation=None, weights=None, W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None, bias=True, input_dim=None)

where

> **input_dim**: dimensionality of the input (integer). This argument (or alternatively, the keyword argument input_shape) is required when using this layer as the first layer in a model.

Comment: Thanks again...Now I got: `ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected dense_input_3 to have shape (None, 1000) but got array with shape (1000, 68)`... Also, sorry this is the first time I am using keras, I am also reading the docs..

Comment: please ask a different question in SO and if possible give your full code so that i can run and check. from the error messages, its difficult to identify the error location if your complete code is not provided. ask multiple question if you are facing different problems that will help others when they will see your post.

Comment: Thanks!, I updated and put the full code I am using!

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of a Dense layer is the number of outputs of that layer. So in your case, you have an input with shape (1000, 20), and labels with shape (1000,). This means you have 1000 training samples, with 20 features and each label is one dimensional (and you have 1000 of them). Then you need to modify the model to have a single output:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=dims))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Here I used the fact that you want to implement linear regression to remove the softmax (which is for classification), and use the mean square error loss instead of cross entropy.

Comment: Thanks!, I got ethe following trace: `ValueError: Invalid objective: mean_square_error`

Comment: @tumbleweed See update, its squared, not square :) You can also use mse as loss, its the same.

Comment: Huh... in the fitting I got: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: @tumbleweed Better provide the complete error message, this error can have multiple causes.

Comment: I updated with the full trace, thanks for helping me to understand!